# I want to include pop up pdf in Joomla

Tags: joomla, modal-dialog

I am working on Joomla for nonprofit, and I want the current month newsletter pops up right after the window newsletter window opens up.
Here is the link of newsletter:

[image: newsletter links]

Answer (score 0):

Download this free modal extension. This will allow you to point to the url of the pdf and open upon page load. http://demo.nonumber.nl/index.php/12-modals

Cheers.

Comment: Thank You, but the page load features available only in Pro version which is not free. Do you know any other which can do it in free.

Comment: Here is one by a reputable company. Free Download link is on the same page /http://www.joomlaxtc.com/resources/free-joomla-extensions/modal-box